# How to css style flexible elements to match their parents

Tags: html, css, canvas, flexbox

Illustrated in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christof/buazwhjo):

What I want is a canvas with rounded corners in the center of the site, that becomes bigger when you enlarge the window and gets smaller when you shrink. However neither my canvas-container nor my canvas seem to be able to stretch over their full capacity. What am I doing wrong?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  margin: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

#canvas_container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height:100px;
  min-width:100px;
  height: 100%;
}
#canvas {
  background: #f80;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content"> 
    <div id="canvas_container">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` div already is flexed to fit. So it would suffice to use position `absolute` for the `canvas-container` relative to the `content`, and remove the `min-width` and `min-height`s and there you go!

```
.box .row.content {
  margin: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#canvas_container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.box .row.content {
  margin: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

#canvas_container {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#canvas {
  background: #f80;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row content"> 
    <div id="canvas_container">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To avoid distorting (stretching and squeezing) existing canvas content when resizing with CSS you must always resize the width & height by the same scaling factor. So if you double the canvas's original width you must also double the canvas height or the content will be distorted.

Comment: @markE could you please tell me how I can do that here, with JS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that your project is the one shown in the JSFiddle (as the CSS you provided is different from the JSFiddle). Adding this should fix it:

```
#canvas_container {
  height: 100%;
}

#canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: To avoid distorting (stretching and squeezing) existing canvas content when resizing with CSS you must always resize the width & height by the same scaling factor. So if you double the canvas's original width you must also double the canvas height or the content will be distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add code

```
#canvas_container {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

#canvas {
    background: #f80;
    display: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* or
#canvas {
    background: #f80;
    display: inherit;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 15%;
    left: 15%;
}
*/
```

Comment: To avoid distorting (stretching and squeezing) existing canvas content when resizing with CSS you must always resize the width & height by the same scaling factor. So if you double the canvas's original width you must also double the canvas height or the content will be distorted.